# Why can't Dart's "Process.start" execute an Ubuntu command when the command works in Ubuntu terminal?

Tags: ubuntu, dart, child-process, dart-io

I have command I would like to call with Dart.

The command is `sonar-runner` which works perfectly if I run it in a normal Ubuntu terminal. This is because I have edited the `PATH` in the `.profile` file so it becomes a global command.

However, if I wrote a simple `Process.start` code that should trigger the same thing:

```dart
Process.run('sonar-runner', []).then((result) {
  stdout.write(result.stdout);
  stderr.write(result.stderr);
});
```

I get as a response:

```dart
Uncaught Error: ProcessException: No such file or directory
  Command: sonar-runner 
Unhandled exception:
ProcessException: No such file or directory
  Command: sonar-runner
```

I am guessing this is an Ubuntu configuration thing, as I have no problem running `ping localhost` via Dart in the same way.

What could be wrong, so that a third party application cannot find global commands when running it as a new process?

**UPDATED - SOLUTION WAS FOUND**

I found the solution to my problem, as described here:

[Set Environment variable using Process.start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13938217/set-environment-variable-using-process-start)

For my specific case, this code worked:

```dart
Process.run("bash", ["-c", "sonar-runner"]).then((result) {
  stdout.write(result.stdout);
  stderr.write(result.stderr);
});
```

Comment: Did you start the Dart script from the same shell/terminal like you started `sonar-runner` directly?

Comment: I found the solution to my problem, as described here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13938217/set-environment-variable-using-process-start

Comment: What did you do, pass the path to `Process.run()`?

Comment: Ive updated my original post to include that :)

Comment: What does that mean? Is `sonar-runner` not an executable but a bash script?

Comment: @corgrath, solution provided by @mezoni does the same as your workaround do, from [the docs](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-io.Process#id_run,runInShell): "If [runInShell] is true, the process will be spawned through a system shell. On Linux and Mac OS, `/bin/sh` is used [...]".

Comment: @Claudiod'Angelis I tried using runInShell and all other optional parameters, none of them work. This did though.

Answer (score 3):

Try this approach `run it in a normal Ubuntu terminal`:

```dart
Process.run('sonar-runner', [], runInShell: true).then((result) {
  stdout.write(result.stdout);
  stderr.write(result.stderr);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be that 'sonar-runner' can not be found, have you tried with the full path ?