# Unable to execute Ubuntu bash command with Process.run

Tags: dart, dart-io

I have a simple command I want to execute and process the result back in Dart, but I am failing to do this on my Ubuntu server.

On my Windows desktop, I can execute this without problems, but I am not able to create the correct command in Ubuntu.

This is what I am trying (I got this from [Why can't Dart's "Process.start" execute an Ubuntu command when the command works in Ubuntu terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25567795/why-cant-darts-process-start-execute-an-ubuntu-command-when-the-command-work)):

```dart
Process.run('bash', ['-c', '/usr/bin/python -V']).then((ProcessResult results) {     
      print(results.stdout);
      print(results.stderr);      
    });
```

When I execute this, I get the following error:

```dart
bash: /usr/bin/python: No such file or directory
```

Obviously, python is installed, available at /usr/bin/python and is working fine.
The strange thing is, executing this works fine:

```dart
Process.run('bash', ['-c', 'git version']).then((ProcessResult results) {     
      print(results.stdout);
      print(results.stderr);      
    });
```

I can't see any difference in executing the python command versus the git command...

Can anyone see something wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Works for me with Debian.

Comment: I don't see any issues with the code. Works for me on both Ubuntu and Mac OS. Please double check your /usr/bin/python. If I change /usr/bin/python to something which cannot be found I get the error you see.

Comment: try 'which python' to see valid python path you have.

Comment: I'm surprised that works for you. On windows, I can't run `Process.run('bash', ...)` and I can't find anything that says anything about it one way or the other